# extends de twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

estoy empezando a usar smfony y me han surgido algunas dudas, tengo la siguiente plantilla base:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>{% block title %}Icebird{% endblock %}</title>
            {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block header %}Esto es un Header{% endblock %} 
        {% block nav %}Aqui hay una barra de navegación{% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}Aqui hay un footer{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Quisiera tener el codigo que hay dentro del bloque de header, nav y footer en otro archivo ya que es bastante extenso y me gustaria tenerlo ordenado, estoy intentando crear un archivo `header.html.twig` y alli poner el codigo, luego hacer un extends en base y incluir las etiquetas del header (`{% block header %}{% endblock %}`) en base pero me da error, alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo suelo hacer para ello es meter todos esos archivos de plantilla en un directorio dentro de templates (por ejemplo includes) y llamar desde el frontend.html.twig a cada uno de ellos:

```
{% block header %}
   {{ include("includes/header.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
   {{ include("includes/navbar.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
   {{ include("includes/footer.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Perfecto, aunque los paréntesis se pueden omitir:
{{ include "includes/header.html.twig" }}